# from Ireland and Rosen: when a prime remains inertial

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm reading Ireland and Rosen's number theory book, and i'm having trouble with proposition 13.1.3 ii):

Let F be $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt d)}$ where $d$ is a square free integer,and $p$ and odd prime, and $P$ a prime ideal of the ring of integers containing $p$. Then If $p$ does not divide the discriminant of F and 
$x^2\equiv d\pmod p$ is not solvable in Z it follows $(p)=P$.

In the proof it supposes the degree of $P$ is 1 so that $D/P$ and $\mathbb{Z}$/$p\mathbb{Z}$ both have $p$ elements. Why is this important? They then go on to state you can find an integer '$a$' such that $a\equiv\sqrt d\pmod P$. How is this so?

And lastly, where do we use the condition $p$ doesn't divide the discriminant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the proof is by contradiction. You don't want $p$ to divide the discriminant because primes dividing the discriminant are exactly the ramified ones, and so they never remain prime in the ring of integers $\mathcal O_F$ of $F$. Now assume that $p\mathcal O_F$ is not a prime ideal. Then there exists a prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subseteq \mathcal O_F$ such that $\mathfrak p\cap \mathbb Z=p\mathbb Z$ and $\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak p\simeq \mathbb F_p$. Now take the reduction map $\pi\colon \mathcal O_F\to \mathcal O_F/\mathfrak p\simeq \mathbb F_p$. Since $\sqrt{d}\in \mathcal O_F$, it is mapped via $\pi$ to some element $u\in \mathbb F_p$. But then $d$ is mapped to $u^2$, and therefore the equation $x^2=d$ admits the solution $x=u$ in $\mathbb F_p$, and this is a contradiction.

By the way, not only the converse is true as well, but for any number field $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$, the splitting behaviour of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ modulo $p$ reflects exactly the splitting behaviour of the ideal $(p)$ in the number ring of $K$. You can find a proof of this fact on Marcus' book "Number Fields".

Comment: why is the  assumption $\mathfrak p\subseteq \mathcal O_F$ is not prime needed? Also, I see that you eventually come to the solution $x=u$ but that is for the prime subfield. But how does that show that $x^2\equiv d\pmod p$ is solvable in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Also, can you clarify the book's wording and technique? The book sticks with the bijection between  D/P and          $\mathbb{Z}$/$p\mathbb{Z}$ .

Comment: If $x^2\equiv d$ is solvable in $\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak p$, then it is solvable in $\mathbb F_p$, because these two rings are isomorphic. Saying that $x^2\equiv d$ is solvable modulo $p$ amounts to say that there exists $a\in \mathbb Z$ with $a^2\equiv d\bmod p$, just by definition.

Comment: thanks. but two more questions: 1)how does $x^2=d$ have a solution in $F_{p}$ when $d$ is in $\mathcal O_F$ and not $F_p$?.  2) why do  ou assume $p\mathcal O_F$is not a prime ideal?

Comment: forget the question I asked about why we assume $p\mathcal O_F$ is not prime as I misread something...  however, I still don't understand how $x^2=d$ has a solution in $F_p$ given that $d$ is in $\mathcal O_F$ and not $F_p$, and these two fields are not isomorophic. thanks

Comment: $\mathcal O_F$ is not a field, but $\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak p$ IS a field, and is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_p$. Of course when you say that $x^2=d$ has a solution in $\mathbb F_p$ you are considering $d$ as an element of $\mathbb F_p$, namely the image of $d\in \mathcal O_F$ via the projection onto $\mathcal O_F/\mathfrak p$

Comment: I understand $\mathcal O_F /mathfrak p$ and $F_p$ are isomorphic and if one field has a solution so does the other, but my problem is I don't see how those two fields have a solution to $x^2=d$. I understand there is a solution to this equation in $\mathcal O_F$, but I don't see how you bridge the gap between having a solution in $\mathcal O_F$and having one in $F_p$

Comment: anyone have input?

Comment: never mind, understood. i read over your previous answer.